# How do I zoom in / zoom out in Adobe Flash?

Tags: mouse, flash, zoom, flash-cs6

I am using Adobe Flash CS6, and I am having troubles with the zoom feature in the editor. I am aware that there is a drop down menu where you can select the zoom level you want, but that is not usable at all. I need to be able to zoom in/out using my mouse wheel. Pressing an extra button is no problem, as I use CTRL+mouse wheel all the time in other applications. But in Flash, it seems you can only zoom in/out with the drop down menu.

Is there any way to get Adobe Flash to use the mouse wheel to zoom?
Or is there already a keyboard shortcut I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using windows:
In flash one must hold SHIFT and CTRL (CTRL + SHIFT + mouse wheel), which doesn't really make sense since in all the other adobes softwares zooming works with ALT+ mouse. Maybe flash is just the weird one :P

If you're using Mac:
Sorry, no clue

Source: Went through same dilemma.

Comment: Thanks! That works! Also, I discovered CTRL+= and CTRL+- to zoom in and out, but that's nowhere near as useful as CTRL+SHIFT+mouse wheel. Thanks again!